# r - for loop returns all zeroes when segmenting a beta distribution

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to segment a beta distribution, but the for loop returns a vector of zeroes:

```
my_vector <- vector("numeric", 11L)
prob <- seq(from = 0.0, to = 1, by = 0.1)
for (i in prob ) {
     my_vector[i] <- dbeta(i, shape1=7, shape2=2)
}
my_vector
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: `my_vector <- dbeta(prob, shape1=7, shape2=2)` You can not indexing with doubles (`my_vector[i]`)! e.g. `my_vector[0.1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it using the for loop, you may do it like this:

```
my_vector <- vector("numeric", 0)
prob <- seq(from = 0.0, to = 1, by = 0.1)
for (i in prob) {
  my_vector <- c(my_vector, dbeta(i, shape1=7, shape2=2))
}

my_vector
[1] 0.0000000 0.0000504 0.0028672 0.0285768 0.1376256 0.4375000 1.0450944 1.9765032 2.9360128 2.9760696 0.0000000
```

Or you better follow the suggestion of @ jogo by doing it like this:

```
prob <- seq(from = 0.0, to = 1, by = 0.1)
my_vector <- dbeta(prob, shape1=7, shape2=2)
```